# Apache Ignite gives inactive cluster error

Tags: ignite

```
class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Unexpected DDL operation failure: Can not perform the operation because the cluster is inactive. Note, that the cluster is considered inactive by default if Ignite Persistent Store is used to let all the nodes join the cluster. To activate the cluster call Ignite.active(true).
```

I am getting the above error, when the below code of lines were pasted in example-default.xml file.

```
 <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
       <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
          <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
             <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
             </bean>
          </property>
       </bean>
    </property>
```

Comment: I know that the below code has to be used, but i want apache ignite to be started outside my application (that is via command prompt)

Comment: `Ignition.setClientMode(true);
 Ignite objIgnite = Ignition.start("F:\\apache-ignite-fabric-2.0.0-bin\\config\\itc-poc-config.xml");                                                                                                       objIgnite.active(true);

Comment: `bin\control.bat --activate`
Something fail during activation, exception message: Latest topology update failed.
Press any key to continue . . .                                                                                                     To activate the cluster i used the above command and it throws error - following it

Comment: Are you trying to use Ignite 2.0? It has a pretty raw version of persistence feature. Could you try to do the same on the latest version?

Comment: @Dennis - I m using apache ignite 2.3.0

Comment: @Dennis - I changed to 2.5 version, and it is working fine....

Answer (score 0):

You can try running

```
bin\control.bat --host 127.0.0.1 --port 11211 --activate
```

after starting all cluster nodes to activate it from command line. If that gives any errors, please share discovery section of your configuration.

Comment: By default it's 11211, also try 11212.

Comment: <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
             
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                 <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>

Comment: I tired the command u sent, still gives "Latest topology failed to update"

Comment: @Pooja Maybe you have disabled the client endpoint 11211? Maybe you have some other Ignite instances running that need to be killed?

Comment: Could you please provide the output of next ./control.bat --host 127.0.0.1 --port 11211 --baseline? Did you see any nodes in output? If no then check that you don't have the ignite nodes with different versions online at the same time.

Comment: ` ./control.bat --host 127.0.0.1 --port 11211 --baseline`                                                    I executed the above, it shows "Latest topology failed to update"

Comment: @alamar - How to check whether the client endpoint 11211 is disabled and kill the running instances????

Comment: `control.bat --state` - command also gives me "Latest topology update fails"

Comment: Apache ignite is stared from command prompt. From my java app, if i try to print the below `System.out.println(Ignition.ignite().getOrCreateCache("cacheName"));` . It throws " Ignite instance with provided name doesn't exist. Did you call Ignition.start(..) to start an Ignite instance? [name=null] "

Comment: If i have started from command prompt... Why is it asking to start again

Comment: @Pooja you have to start Ignite node (server or client) in your java app to be able to communicate with Ignite cluster.

Comment: Why cant it be from outside and access its instance???? I just wanted to clarify alamar

Comment: @Pooja you can use [JDBC](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jdbc-driver#jdbc-thin-driver) to access Ignite instance from outside, but for most operation you need a node.

Comment: Yes. You can also use REST.

Comment: @Pooja as VARCHAR perhaps? Please ask new questions using 'Ask Question' button.